# Does the FIFA 15 Demo support multiplayer?

Tags: fifa-15

In the recently released demo version of FIFA 15, is it possible to play multiplayer at all?

So essentially, when you go to "kick off" and during the controller select screen, can you use multiple controllers as you would be able to in the full version?

Unfortunately, it is not something I can test as I only have a single controller for my PS4. The reason I ask is because I want to know if it is worth inviting a friend around who is able to bring a second controller.

Comment: Not 100% but I know once you beat Man City, It lets you choose more teams so I'd imagine you can choose sides and add another play like older FIFA demos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can play with someone else if you've got 2 or more controllers. You can't play online matches in the demo version.